# Setting project title with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, title

I am trying to change the project's title in a Python macro. But there is a mistake I cannot solve:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setTitle';.

Can you help me?

This is the code I am using:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def saveProject():

title = QgsProject.instance().title()

 
title.setTitle("HOLAAA")
```

Comment: Hi Tania, welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. I edited your question, but in future, please don't use all caps in your question titles- it tends to attract a lot of down votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [setTitle()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProject.html#aa79248815d5f3dc5385d590a1abd091f) method belongs to the `QgsProject` class, but you are trying to call it on the string object which is returned when you retrieve the current title.

As per the docs, this method provides:

> a shortcut to setting the title in the project's metadata()

So, to set the title in the project's metadata, you can just do:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.setTitle('Holaaa')
project.write()
```

This will not rename the .qgz project file. To also do that at the same time, you would need to do something like:

```py
import os

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.setTitle('Holaaa')
project.write()

old_file = project.fileName()
new_file = os.path.join(project.homePath(), 'Holaaa.qgz')
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Tania, you're welcome :-) If the answer solved your problem, would you mind accepting it using the check mark? https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers